# Changing page title as a Facebook app

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-apps

I wonder if I could change my page title of my [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook)application. At the moment the page is entitled "CoolApplicationName on Facebook", I would like to add one word before my application name. For example "(AddedWord) CoolApplicationName on Facebook". Is it possible or page title is imposed by [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook)and it can't be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a programming question, but more of a [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook)settings thing. These are the steps on how to update the title of your [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook)application:

1. Log into the [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/) site.
2. Click on "My apps".
3. Click on the app's name to go to its dashboard.
4. On the left menu, click on "Settings".
5. Update the "Display Name" and add the new word.
6. Save changes.

When you reload your game, the page title will be the new one that you saved.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?:

```
var oldTitle = document.title;
document.title = "(AddedWord) " + oldTitle;
```

Comment: It changes my inner page title but not the facebook frame title.